# Whats is better two functions or one to create a user

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using codeigniter to create a login and  users registration , I have a  doubt:

What is better to use if two function one to show for example the register form and other to process the form like this:

```
     public function Register()
{
     //show the form of register
}

public function create_user()
{   
      // create user
    }
```

Or something like this:

```
function register(){
   if(btnSubmit == false){
         show the form
else{
     create the user
```

}

Comment: make it RESTful and have the http GET variant show the form and have the POST variant do the db work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What castis means by his comment is that you'll display the form with one function while setting the `action` attribute to a different function, that runs your logic for creating new users.

so one function for presentation and one function for manipulation.